# Android - Why attributes TextAppearanceLarge and TextAppearanceMedium define different text colors

Tags: android

There are 3 styles in styles.xml file:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

TextAppearance.Small has different color but TextAppearance.Large and TextAppearance.Medium should have the same color.

If set these style in TextView:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

and

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

they have a slightly different color.

Why and where can I find these colors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the declaration of a attribute or method **Right-Click on the attribute** -> open **Go-To submenu** -> Click on **Declaration** or use the shortcut **Strg + B**

Now you see the **attrs.xml** from your choosen theme.

There is a inline comment that shows you the style reference.

In my case I use a Light Theme that has different colors for different text sizes.